# How to select particular column when using join in active record

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, yii, model

I have tables

1)topic_tag_map.
columns: id,topic_id,tag_id,version_name
2)tagging
columns: id and tag_name

Foreign key is tag_id and id

For both of the tables I created model and defined relations like this:

In topic_tag_map

```
'topic' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Topic', 'topic_id'), 

'tagging' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Tagging', 'tag_id'),
```

Here I only want to fetch the tag_name from tagging table.
So I tried this:

```
$tags = TopicTagMap::model()->with(array(
            'tagging'=>array(
                'select' => 'tagging.tag_name',
                'joinType'=>'INNER JOIN',
                'condition' => 'topic_id = '.$topic->id.' and version_name = 1',
                ),
            ))->findAll();
```

But it is giving all the columns.

After that I have tried this also:

```
$tags = TopicTagMap::model()->findAll(array(
            'select' => 'tagging.tag_name',
            'condition' => 'topic_id = '.$topic->id.' and version_name = 1',
            'with' => 'tagging',
            ));
```

But this throwing error:
Invalid column name

Comment: plz guys help that is serious problem

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it like this:

```
   $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
   $criteria->with = 'tagging';
   $criteria->select = 'tagging.tag_name';
   $criteria->together = true;
   $criteria->addCondition('t.topic_id = '.$topic->id, 'AND');
   $criteria->addCondition('t.version_name = 1', 'AND');

   $tags = TopicTagMap::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

You have to define relation in `Tagging` Model as

```
   'tag_map' => array(self::HAS_MANY,'TopicTagMap','tag_id'),
   //You can use self::HAS_MANY or self::HAS_ONE or self::MANY_MANY on your tables relationship type.
```

Comment: No not working but I am getting this error
Active record "TopicTagMap" is trying to select an invalid column "tagging.tag_name". Note, the column must exist in the table or be an expression with alias.

Comment: Sorry my bad forgot to set together property of CDbCriteria to true.

Comment: No I didn't defined any relation in tagging model

Comment: try creating `tag_map` relation (above in the answer) in your `Tagging` Model and check. Hope it will work now.

Comment: Still is not working I added relation in tagging model and tried again but throwing the same error

Answer (score 0):

The way you have given would cause sql injection just use params.

For the Active record to use the relation you just need to add this

```
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->with = 'tagging';
    $criteria->together = true;
    $criteria->select = 'tagging.tag_name';
    $criteria->addCondition('t.topic_id = :tId');
    $criteria->addCondition('t.version_name = 1');
    $criteria->params = array(":tId" => $topic->id);
    $tags = TopicTagMap::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Hope this would solve your problem

Comment: This also giving same error

Active record "TopicTagMap" is trying to select an invalid column "tagging.tag_name". Note, the column must exist in the table or be an expression with alias.